# Can YADCF support Select2 filled with ajax?

Tags: ajax, datatables, jquery-select2, yadcf

YADCF has support to use Select2 for its filters. Select2 has support for Ajax ([Source](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax)). But does YADCF allow to use this Ajax option of Select2?

I tried to use it inside the `select_type_options`, inside the filter settings:

```
(...)
{column_number : 5, select_type: 'select2', filter_type: 'multi_select', filter_container_id: 'external_filter_container_6', select_type_options: { dropdownAutoWidth: true, placeholder: 'Select', ajax: {...} }},
(...)
```

Doing that YADCF throws an error in the console that says something like:

Ajax is not supported with select2 when attached to a select...

So, is possible to use the Ajax support of Select2 when using it inside YADCF?

Thanks

Comment: You should use select 4 (use latest version) to allow ajax with select2, also read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190088/jquery-select2-not-working. for start you better try ajax with an ordinary (unrelated to yadcf) select element that uses select2, then after it works try with yadcf and see what happens and post a detailed question

Comment: Thank you @Daniel, it really helped! However someone else working on the project decided not to use ajax in this case, so did not test that yet.