# select2 search box dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dropdown

Select2 problem,

I do not want drop down search box, i want to make first line in search,

How can i do?

How do I search by location placeholder?
**CODE :**

```
<select name="search" class="box"></select>
```

Example pictures,

[image: First Picture]

[image: Second Picture]

```
$(".box").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,          
    placeholder: ' Search!',
  cache:true,
     ajax: {
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        delay: 400,
        data: function(params) {
            return {
                term: params.term
            }
        },
        processResults: function (data, page) {
          return {
            results: data.results
          };
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS, make sure that it appears below the CSS for select2:

```
.select2-drop-active{
    margin-top: -25px;
}
```

#### [Here is a demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ad7A/347/)

Note that this will effect all of your select2 elements. To target specific elements, simply adjust the selector for the rule to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i like it but ajax not working right now , Uncaught Error: Option 'ajax' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a <select> element.

Comment: That is really a new question, but it would just be a duplicate of [jquery select2 - not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190088/jquery-select2-not-working), the answer there suggests to update to [Select2 4.0](https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html) or use a hiden `input` element instead of a `select` element

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yacCe.png)    $("select#currency(class or id name)").select2({
tags : true,
createTag : function(params) {
return undefined;
}
});

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: you have added an additional files of this functions...these are select2 and jquiery vendor files

Comment: <script
    src="<?php echo Config::WORK_ROOT; ?>vendor/components/jquery/jquery.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script
    src="<?php echo Config::WORK_ROOT; ?>vendor/select2/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link
    href="<?php echo Config::WORK_ROOT; ?>vendor/select2/css/select2.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: Please [do not post pictures of text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), put that text in your post (with appropriate markup).

Comment: yah ok...but this is an only reference dude.